# How to back up specific rows in multiple tables with foreign keys, then restore with relationships intact from a large db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Using Rails 5.2.3, PSQL 11.1

I have a db that has many tables, and each table has a substantial number of rows. I would like to be able to pull out specific rows from certain tables and move the data out to a cold storage server and then be able to restore the data with all the FK relationships still there.

Previously, I was using a worker to pull out the data, then generate a JSON of the data and send it to storage. But, due to an increase in the number of records and the addition of a few tables, it makes the requisite book keeping more challenging. For example, parsing the large JSON file and maintaining the relationships is going require a lot of work (correct me if I am wrong) once the file lands back in the Rails app. For examples, 20,000 records that each have multiple records in subordinate tables, that in turn have records in other tables. I would prefer not to parse that data back from a JSON while re-establishing the relationships on the fly. If this is the only way to do it, that is fine, I just figure there has to be a better way.

I'm familiar with SQL dumps, but only for entire tables. But, I was thinking that it would be possible to dump rows with FKs, so I have been investigating it - which is what brought me here.

So, long story short. I am looking for help/recommendations:

Is generating a potentially massive JSON file best?

Can a sql dump be created that allows specific data to be re-inserted into a bunch of tables with FK retained?

Are there any solutions that I haven't thought of?

Comment: You could create views (as in DB views, not MVC) which contain the data you want and dump them with pg_dump.

Comment: Thanks, I believe that is the best way to do. It shouldn't be too hard to maintain the FKs in the dump, correct?